Symfony detecting removed column which has already been removed
Currently, I'm working on a project using Symfony 5 and Docker. Recently I've removed a column from a table. I've updated everything accordingly for that. But after deployment, it still detects that column and gives error -
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.is_active' in 'field list'.

Any idea what could be the reason? FYI, I didn't rebuild the docker during deployment.

Obviously you still have mentioning of this column somewhere in the code

Removed everything related to this column. Properly updated it everywhere. Didn't even face any kind of error during migrate command
